# Under 18 year old overstay in the US returned back to Europe, am I still able to re enter the US?

Tags: visas, usa, overstaying, minors

My question is am I eligible to re enter the US? In more detail, I have overstayed my US visa for a couple of month in which my mother has received her green card therefore she can enter the US, however the question is can I enter the US past my overstay? I was 14-15 when I overstayed there so are there any explanations to my question. 
The difference however is that my mother was there mainly to apply for a green card and we lived with my sister whose 32 which sponsored her for the green card. Is there any possible way I am able to return to the US?

Comment: The other question is, why haven't you [gotten a green card](http://www.uscis.gov/green-card/green-card-through-family/green-card-family-member-permanent-resident)?

Comment: How old are you now? Are you still under 21? Do you want to visit or immigrate?

Answer (score 0):

From what you described, you should have no ban. But not having a ban does not mean you will be granted a visa.